# Return nil object if after_initialize callback returns false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, rails-activerecord

My Rails app has many models that form a hierarchy.  For example:  Retailer > Department > Product Category > Product > Review.

A business requirement is that high-authority users can "share" any individual element in the hierarchy with a new or existing "normal" user.  Without having an object shared with them, normal users have no rights to see (or do anything else) with any object in any level of the hierarchy.

The sharing process includes a choice of whether the share grants permission to read-only, read-update, or full CRUD on the target object.

Sharing any object grants R/O, R/W or CRUD permission to that object and all lower level objects in the hierarchy, and R/O permission to all of the direct ancestors of the object.  The object collection grows organically, so the permission system works by just logging the user_id, the object_id of the share, and the nature of the share (R/O, CRUD, etc).  As the population of objects in this hierarchy grows all the time, it is impractical to create an explicit permission record in the DB for every user/object combination.

Instead, at the start of the user request cycle, `ApplicationController` gathers all the permission records (user X has CRUD permission to Department #5) and holds them in a hash in memory.  A Permissions model knows how to evaluate the hash when any object is passed to it - Permission.allow?(:show, Department#5) would return true or false depending on the content of the user's permission hash.

Let's take, for example, the Department model:

```
# app/models/department.rb
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_initialize :check_permission

  private

  def check_permission
    # some code that returns true or false 
  end

end
```

When the `check_permission` method returns true, I want `Department.first` to bring back the first record in the database as normal, BUT, if `check_permission` returns false, I want to return `nil`.

Right now, I have a solution whereby default scopes trigger a permissions check, but this is causing 2X the number of queries, and for classes with a lot of objects, memory problems and time/performance issues are sure to be on the horizon.

My goal is to use `after_initialize` callbacks to pre-permission the objects.

It would appear however that `after_initialize` is unable to block the original object from being returned.  It does allow me to reset the values of the attributes of the object, but not to dispense with it.

Anybody know how to achieve this?

EDIT:

Many thanks for all of the answers and comments offered so far; hopefully this extended version of the question clarifies things.

Comment: `after_initialize` doesn't do what you expecting it to do. It is there to perform some side effects. It doesn't return you anything. What exactly your need/requirement is ?

Comment: I think you shouldn't be trying to do this, I think there's no permission system that can intercept at that level because it's not the level you should be doing it at. You should probably have a relationship between User and Department instead. what is `check_permission` actually checking?

Comment: There is no direct relationship between the user and the department.  The Rails app in question has a hierarchy of objects (e.g. Tenant, Department, Product Category, Product, etc).  Permissions can be granted to a specific object at any level; all children inherit the full permission, and all ascendants inherit read-only permission.  The "check_permission" method calls an ActiveModel model to find out of the specific object (Department #1, etc) is permitted for the user.

Answer (score 5):

Basically you need to check for access rights (or permissions) before returning a database query result. And you are trying to integrate this logic into your models.

It is possible, but not with the design you described in your question. It is not clean to implement this directly in ActiveRecord adapter methods (such as `first`, `all`, `last` etc...). You need to rethink your design.

*(skip to point 'D' if this is too much reading)*

You have several choices, which all depend on the way your permissions are defined. Let's look at few cases:

**A.** A user have a list of departments he *owns* and only him can access them

You can simply implement this as a `has_many`/`belongs_to` association with [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

**B.** Users and Departments are independent (in other words: no *ownership* such as described in the previous case) and permission can be set individually for each users and each departments.

Simply again, you can implement a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association with [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). You will need to create web logic so the administrator of your application can add/edit/remove access rights.

**C.** More complex case: the existing authorization libraries

Most people will turn to authorization solutions such as [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) or [other](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization)

**D.** When those authorization libraries are oversized for your needs (actually, my case in most of my projects), I found that implementing authorization through rails [scoping](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) answers all my needs.

Let's see it through a simple example. I want administrators to be able to access the whole database records ; and regular users to access only departments with *status = open* and only during operation hours (say 8am-6pm). I write a scope that implement my permission logic

```
# Class definition
class Department
  scope :accessible_by -> (user) do
    # admin user have all access, always
    if user.is_admin?
      all
    # Regular user can access only 'open' departments, and only
    # if their request is done between 8am and 6pm
    elsif Time.now.hour >= 8 and Time.now.hour <= 18
      where status: 'open'
    # Fallback to return ActiveRecord empty result set
    else
      none
    end
  end
end

# Fetching without association
Department.accessible_by(current_user)

# Fetching through association
Building.find(5).departments.accessible_by(current_user)
```

Defining a scope obliges us to use it everywhere in our code. You can think of the risk to "forget" going through the scope and accessing directly the model (i.e writing `Department.all` instead of `Department.accessible_by(current_user)`). So that's why you must solidly test your permissions in your specs (at the controller or features level).

*Note* In this example we do not return `nil` when the permission fails (as you mentioned in your question), but an empty result set instead. It is generally better so you keep the ActiveRecord method chaining capability. But you could also raise an exception and rescue it from your controller then redirect to a 'not authorized' page for example.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts on this.  I take your point regarding "nil" versus "empty result".  However, the permissions setup in this Rails app is much more complex.  It isn't possible to have a direct RDBMS-type relationship between the user and the permitted objects.  The "Department" is one of a number of levels in a hierarchy.  E.g., the hierarchy could look like Tenant > Department > Category > Product > Reviews.  Any object in the hierarchy could have permissions granted to it; then, all children inherit all permissions from the grantee, and direct parent objects become read-only.

Comment: Your particular answer is details it in my point 'D', which does not rely on database relations, hence I believe you did not read/understand it. Keep in mind this question and answer are easily accessible through google, that's why I made my answer general by explaining different solutions that exist. Please check more into it; there is no limit to this solution, and you can implement very complex permission logic in that way. Also check for point 'C' if you need a framework to it.

Comment: Actually, that's the solution I came up with as a work-around before creating the question.  I do it slightly differently: I ask the permissions model to give me a list of IDs (as an array) for all of the objects that are permission-granted, and then scope based on that.  The problem with this approach is that it causes 2X queries.  I think I feel the need to create a new callback and offer it to the Rails overlords. :)

Comment: Can't you avoid the 2X queries by using nested queries? More specially if one query must return a series of ID to another query.

Comment: In order to use join/include queries, I would need a table with every single possible permission ready to be queried.  To do that, I'd need to have expensive callbacks on almost every model that checked for every user IF they should have permission to the object, and then create or delete their permission.  This would lead to the permissions table being larger than all other tables combined, due to the way permissions are designed.  Admins can grant permission on an umbrella object and grant permission to all children, and read-only permission to all direct ancestors.

Comment: The more you give details, the more I understand that your question is not completely describing the whole picture. Each solution proposed to you is subject to additional details revealed. Why didn't you explain everything in the original post? Well good luck to you, but I'll give up here.

Answer (score 1):

That is not what the `after_initialize` callback is used for. Instead, you could just define a method that does the same thing. For example, put this in your `Department` model and it should achieve the results you are looking for:

```
def self.get_first
  check_permission ? first : nil
end
```

**UPDATE**

I'm not exactly sure how safe something like this would be, but you could just override the `all` method as the other query methods are based off of it.

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.all
    check_permission ? super : super.none
  end

  private

  def self.check_permission
    # some code that returns true or false 
  end
end
```

You are probably better off using some authorization framework though.

**UPDATE 2**

Thinking about this a little more, I strongly recommend using a different approach. You really shouldn't be overriding methods like `all` as there will surely be unintended side effects.

A practical alternative would be to create a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between `Department` and `User`. Here is how you would set it up:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :departments
  ...
end
```

**department.rb**

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  ...
end
```

Then run these commands in your terminal:

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableDepartmentsUsers departments users
rake db:migrate
```

Now you can add users to a department with `@department.users << @user`, or departments to a user with `@user.departments << @department`. This should achieve the functionality that you are looking for.

`@user.departments` will return only departments for that user, `@user.departments.first` will return the first department for that user or `nil` if it doesn't have any, and `@user.departments.find(1)` will return the corresponding department only if it belongs to the user or throw an exception otherwise.

Comment: I used Department.first as an example of using a general purpose record retrieval command.  I would like the same functionality from Department.all, etc.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.  `check_permission` is an instance method.  I tried this with limited success;

    def self.all
      super.collect { |x| x.check_permission}.exclude?(false) ? super : super.none
    end

Department.first, Department.all worked. Department.find(1) did not.

Comment: Ok, then could you explain more clearly the functionality you are looking for? Do you want `all` to return only the departments that have `check_permission` return true? Do you want `first` to return the first department where `check_permission` is true? Etcetera. Also, `Department.find` is not based on `all` like most of the other query methods are. Instead, you have to do `Department.all.find`.

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly.  Let's say I have three Departments [1,2,3], and user A is permitted to have access to 1 and 2, but not 3.  Department.all should return an AR::Relation with Departments 1 and 2 included; Department.first should give department 1, Department.last should give Department 2, and Department.find(3) should return nil.  Department.find(1) and Department.find(2) should return the departments requested.

Comment: Re: Update 2 – The issue here is that implicit permissions to objects can be derived from explicit permission to a parent (or grand-parent).  This would mean that every time a child object is created, we would have to spawn an unpredictably large number of permission records.  The permissions table would become the largest table in the system.  Every time permission changed, or an object was created or destroyed, there would be a large number of permission records to be updated.

Comment: Good idea. I will update the original question with more detail.  Thank you very much for all of your input. You have been very generous.

Answer (score 1):

You can use before_create callback to stop record creation if check permission is false. Just return false in check_permission filter and record will be not created.

```
 class Department < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :check_permission

  private

  def check_permission
    # return false if permission is not allowed 
  end

end
```

Comment: sorry, this is out of the question, the permission system should work on the instantiation step even before validation and creation

Comment: In fact, enforcing permissions on create or update is easy enough, and your solution is how I do it (and you are therefore correct).  However, the original question is specifically about READING data back form the database, subject to permissions.

Comment: I think you should check where you want the user to access department and use some kind of authorization mechanism like CanCan or write your own. I saw you comment in which you wrote that if a user doesn't have permission on lets say dep3 then Department.find(3) should return nil that can never happen as find doesn't have the knowledge about who the accessor is. You have to restrict user to not accessing this record. You should use CanCan, it has a method authorize! which can restrict a user to see a particular record if that user doesn't have the permission to that record at controller level

Comment: @MuhammadJunaid - actually, I started out with CanCanCan and had to drop it.  It was causing hundreds of queries to be fired on every request cycle (because of the way our system grants permissions).  In the Ability model, we instantiated an Ability object with calculated explicit permissions to every object the user has access to - hence the many many queries.  CanCan(Can) is a good solution in general, but doesn't work for this case (very unfortunately).